# Switch statement inside a while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, break

I have a function which is supposed to act like a cash register. It is suppose to deduct money as long as the change is bigger than 0. However, I don't think the loop or switch statement is working properly as the values are not being deducted and returned to my variable or array. When I view my array the value should be deducted.

The code:

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var change = cash - price;
  var message = "";
  var isBoolean = true;
  var cashInReg = cid;

  while(isBoolean) {
    switch (change) {
        case change -100 > 0:
          change-= 100;
          cashInReg[8][1]-= 100;
          break;
        case change -20 > 0:
          break;
        case change -10 > 0:
          break;
        case change -5 > 0:
          break;
        case change -1 > 0:
          break;
        case change -0.25 > 0:
          break;
        case change -0.10 > 0:
          break;
        case change -0.05 > 0:
          break;
        case change -0.01 > 0:
          break;
        case change === 0:
          isBoolean = false;
          break;
        case change < 0:
          message = "Insufficient Funds";
          isBoolean = false;
          break;
      default:
          message = "hi";
    }
  }

  return cashInReg;
}



checkCashRegister(100,500.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]);
```

Comment: The only `case` which modifies `cashInReg` is the first one. Also, you should be using `switch (true)` because all of your cases are boolean values, not numbers.

Comment: @4castle yes, it's just an example. I haven't added the others. My concern is that the whole while loop or switch statement is not working at all.

Comment: It won't work simply change and the case values are different except for the default and case change === 0

Comment: I recommend you use if else construct

Comment: @lazy_coder yup, that's what I am doing right now. Why wouldn't the switch statement work though? Why can't I put change- 100 > 0 for the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

> The switch statement evaluates an expression, matching the
> expression's value to a case clause, and executes statements
> associated with that case.

In your code, normally `change`should be compare to the value in `case` construct which happen to be in (your code a boolean). `case change -100 > 0:`
 I recommend that you use `if else if else if ... else` construct.
 Good luck.